# Custom field filter in Bolt CMS admin panel

Tags: email, encoding, filter, bolt-cms

Is it possible to add custom filter (or validator) to admin panel when saving content type item?
For example, I need to check whether the field contains e-mail address and transform it to some encoded text.

When enter to the field this text:

```
You can contact us - test@test.com
```

an e-mail `"test@test.com"` must be found, converted to base64, and in the database must be saved this text:

```
You can contact us - <script>
document.write(window.atob("dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbQ=="));
</script>
```

It's needed to prevent read e-mails by spam-bots.

Or if there is other solution in Bolt CMS I will be grateful for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own extension that add twig filter to obfuscate emails in frontend. It is a better way than store encoded emails in database. Maybe it will help to someone - https://market.bolt.cm/view/zinitsolutionsgmbh/bolt3-twig-emailobfuscator